# How can I validate email as well as mobile in a single input field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

[image]

Is am using here react hook form to validate the form. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a valid formats of emails and phone numbers using regex. The two below functions will return a boolean indicating if the values are email and phone respectively.

```
function isValidEmail(email) {
  return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
}
```

likewise you can check for a valid phone number using regex like:

```
function isValidPhone(phone){
  return /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/.test(phone);
}
```

You can then combined the two functions together in a validation check for the field.

Such like:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

function isValidEmail(email) {
  return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
}


function isValidPhone(phone){
  return /^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$/.test(phone);
}

  const handleChange = event => {
    if (!(isValidEmail(event.target.value) || (isValidPhone(event.target.value) )) {
      setError('Email is invalid');
    } else {
      setError(null);
    }

    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="message"
        name="message"
        value={message}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      {error && <h2 style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</h2>}
    </div>
  );
}
```